# in react native cli formdata is not working

Tags: react-native, form-data

im trying to post data using formdata but formdata is not working..how can i solve this issue please let me know,,,how can i fixed this in inspector data sent shows perfectly every value got send but then also it shows 400  every single field shows required...same piece of code is working fine in expo but in cli its not working..please let me know what can i do,,,

```
const onPay = async (
current_date,

tests_data,
lab_id,
selectedMember,
time_slot,
health_packages_details,
payment_mode,
) => {
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
dispatch(startSubmitting());
const url = `/auth/make-booking`;

let  formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('lab_partner_id', lab_id);
formdata.append('booking_for', selectedMember);
formdata.append('date', current_date);
formdata.append('time', time_slot);

health_packages_details &&
  formdata.append('health_package_id', health_packages_details);
  tests_data && formdata.append('test_ids[]', tests_data);
formdata.append("payment_mode", payment_mode);

 
const response = await api
  
  .post(
    url, formdata , 
    
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
         
      },
    },
  )

  .then(res => {
     console.log("res hhh", res);
      if (res.data.payment_mode == "ONLINE") {
        initiatePaymentInterface(res.data);
     }
    dispatch({
      type: 'BOOKING',
      payload: response,
    });
    setLoading(false);
    initiatePaymentInterface(res.data);
     
    return res;
  })
  .catch(error => {
      actions.setErrors(error.response.data.error);
    failedPaymentInitiate(error.response);
    setLoading(false);
    
  });
 
dispatch(stopSubmitting());
```

};